# Access Multiple search filter

Tags: c#, ms-access, filter

I am trying to click a search button with multiple inputs on the textbox.
I have looked around and tried different methods but somehow It didn't work out. Below is the code for the click event:

```
private void btn_table_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        string query = "select [Name],[Sex],[Number] from RecordsSheet [Name] like('" + textBox1.Text + "%'),[Sex]=('" + textBox2.Text + "%'),[Number]=('" + textBox3.Text + "%'");

        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently mixing equals and LIKE syntax on the same operations, which is going to result in some incorrectly formed queries, as well as the absence of a WHERE clause to properly use them.

**Use Parameterization**

If you have a specific search term, consider adding it in as a parameter with your LIKE section predefined within your query :

```
// Add your properties using parameters
var query = "SELECT [Name],[Sex],[Number] FROM RecordsSheet WHERE [Name] LIKE ? AND [Sex] LIKE ?,[Number] LIKE ?";
```

Then add your parameters along with the necessary wildcards to build your query :

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
// Set your parameters
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1",textBox1.Text + "*");
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2",textBox2.Text + "*");
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p3",textBox3.Text + "*");
```

This approach will not only lead to resolving issues related to syntax, but it should also help keep you protected from nasty things like SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

with [Sex] and [Number] replace "=" with "like", that may help..
if not post the result description.